# How can I check if two items in a list are from the same key in a python dictionary?

Tags: python

trying to write a code in python that converts a string of letters into their corresponding number on a mobile phone number pad. if two adjacent letters are on the same number pad then I put in a space in the string to show a pause.

i.e. foo bar = 333666 6660222777 and no = 66 666

I have most of the code figured out except for when to put in the space as I'm having trouble figuring out how to check if two items in a list are from the same dictionary key or not.

this is my code:

```
input = open("C-small-practice.in", 'r')
output = open("output.txt", 'w')

T9 = {"0": [" "], "1": [], "2": ["a", "b", "c"], "3": ["d", "e", "f"],
     "4": ["g", "h", "i"], "5": ["j", "k", "l"], "6": ["m", "n", "o"],
     "7": ["p", "q", "r", "s"], "8": ["t", "u", "v"], "9": ["w", "x", "y", "z"]}

N = int(input.readline())

for z in range(N):

    word = input.readline().strip()
    word_list = []
    for char in word:
        word_list.append(char)

    case_word = ""
    for char in range(len(word_list)):
        for key in T9:
            for i in range(len(T9[key])):
                if word_list[char] == T9[key][i]:
                    case_word += key*(i + 1)
                    if char != len(word_list)-1:
                        #if key from word_list[char] ==  key from word_list[char + 1]:
                            #case_word += " "

    output.write("Case #%s: %s\n" % (str(z+1), case_word))

input.close()
output.close()
```

hopefully what I'm trying to do makes sense. I got this problem from practice section in google's code jam site by the way.

Comment: Why don't you invert the dictionary (e.g. map letter to number, rather than vice versa) and simply keep the last number pressed? Then it's a trivial comparison `current_key == last_key`. Also, note that `word_list = list(word)` does the same as your current loop.

Comment: How did you get `foo bar = 333666 6660222777`? Shouldn't it be `3666660222777`?

Comment: @Burhan he says he leaves an space if there's another letter from the same number. That's exactly the point

Comment: @BurhanKhalid it should be `333666 666022 2777`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, your right. my mistake. Also inverting the dictionary is probably looking like the best option

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
for m in range(T9.values().__len__):
    if your_letter in T9.values()[m]:
            your_number = T9.keys()[m]

    if your_other_letter in T9.values()[m]:
            your_other_number = T9.keys()[m]

if your_number == your_other_number:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 4 nested for loops, which I guess are bad. 
Why dont you just create a dict like

```
d = {
 'a': '2',
 'b': '22',
 'c': '222',
 ...,
 ' ': 0
}
```

Basically reverse of what you created.
And then just keep replacing. To donate pause, you can check the last element, and if it has first letter same, then append a space

```
output = []
for i in N:
    if output[-1][0] == d[i][0]:
        output.append(" ")
    output.append(d[i])
```